# Environment variables | Validation Errors when seeding with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I have a rails app that I'm trying to seed data with on Heroku. I'm running `heroku run rake db:seed` and getting the following...

```
Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank
```

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong here. Locally everything runs fine and seeds. It's only with Heroku that I have this problem. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and let me know if you need additional info.

My code:

db/seeds.rb

```
Dog.destroy_all
Admin.destroy_all

Admin.create!(
  email: ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"],
  password: ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"],
  id: 1
)

Dog.create!([
  { 
    location: "92603",
    name: Faker::Name.first_name,
    age: 2,
    title_age: "baby",
    breed: "Corgi" ,
    gender: "female",
    adoptable: true,
    size: "small",
    photo: "http://3milliondogs.com/blog-assets-two/2014/08/corgicute.jpg",
    color: "white, black, orange",
    birth_date: Faker::Date.birthday(1, 9),
    admin_id: 1
  }
```

models/admin.rb

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :dogs
end
```

models/dog.rb

```
class Dog < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  include Gravtastic

  gravtastic :secure => true,
             :filetype => :jpg,
             :size => 250

  scope :location, -> (location) { where location: location }
  scope :breed, -> (breed) { where breed: breed }
  scope :title_age, -> (title_age) { where title_age: title_age }
  scope :gender, -> (gender) { where gender: gender }

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
  validates :title_age, presence: true
  validates :breed, presence: true
  validates :gender, presence: true
  validates :adoptable, presence: true
  validates :size, presence: true

  belongs_to :admin
end
```

~/.bash_profile

```
export ADMIN_EMAIL=gmail@gmail.com
export ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
```

What I've already tried..

Within seeds.rb

```
a = Admin.new(
  email: ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"],
  password: ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"],
  id: 1
)

a.save!(validate: false)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, , null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 2017-08-13 04:45:12.125121, 2017-08-13 04:45:12.125121, ynNjhGEkh_F3iJKzcvEz, null, 2017-08-13 04:45:12.125384).
: INSERT INTO "admins" ("id", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
```

I've also tried it without `validate: false`, but still get "email and password can't be blank".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For heroku local ENV var you should set with config:set, [probably this link can help you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

```
heroku config:set ADMIN_EMAIL=xxx@xxx.com
heroku config:set ADMIN_PASSWORD=xyz
```